# PHP loop through ArrayObject

Tags: php, loops, arrayobject

This is the first time I work with ArrayObjects so maybe I didn't understand it 100% but could you please explain me how to loop through them?

This is my code:

```
$this->plugins = new \ArrayObject(array());
//just for testing...
$this->plugins->plugin1 = "plugin1";
$this->plugins->plugin2 = "plugin2";
$this->plugins->plugin3 = "plugin3";

foreach ($this->plugins as $plugin){
     //never reached
}
```

`$this->plugins->count()` returns 0 and `$this->plugins->getIterator()->valid();` returns false as well.
What do I have to do?

Comment: what if you create a simple array using `$this->plugins->plugin1` ....

Comment: This would be a way to solve it too, but I would like to know how it works with ArrayObjects to understand and learn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have gotten far but this is how it works

```
// You can already have an array like this
$array = array('Buck','Jerry','Tomas');

$arrayObject = new ArrayObject($array);
// Add new element
$arrayObject->append('Tweety');

// We are getting the iterator of the object
$iterator = $arrayObject->getIterator();

// Simple while loop
while ($iterator->valid()) {
    echo $iterator->current() . "\n";
    $iterator->next();
}
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php)

Comment: So I have to use the `append` method in order to make it work? Thank you

Comment: @Anubarak Yes! If this solved your problem please accept the answer so it can help others too.

Comment: Thats what I'm going to do in 4 minutes - I have to wait a little bit :D

Comment: @Anubak You use `append` only when you want to add something to object. If you want to iterate through an object, you don't need use `append` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost ok, only change initialization of variables, so instead `plugins->plugin1 = "plugin1"`, put everything into `array("plugin1", ...)` on the beginning.
So

```
$plugins = new ArrayObject(array("plugin1", "plugin2", "plugin3"));

foreach ($plugins as $plugin){
    echo $plugin . "<br>";
}
```